# problems when linking opencv 4.5.5 with Qt 6.4.2

Tags: c++, opencv, qt6

I built opencv 4.5.5 from source using cmake and mingw with properties WITH_QT=true and added extra modules (opencv_contrib 4.5.5 also) as static libraries. I've been getting some errors (due to some deprecated functions) but fixed them and successfully built the libs.
After that i tried to link those libraries to my Qt 6.4.2 project. Before that i had 4.7.0 libs linked and everything worked fine.
When i'm trying to build my application using those opencv 4.5.5 static libraries i keep getting errors like:

```
error: undefined reference to `cv::softfloat::softfloat(int)'
error: undefined reference to `gzclose'
```

but those modules are in core module or others default modules of OpenCV so i don't really understand why this happens (considering the fact that in 4.7.0 libs it worked just fine)

Then i found out that with usage of gcc there are some conditions like ordering of libraries. I tried the solutions from here ([enter link description here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/186124/undefined-reference-to-cvsoftdoubleoperator/)) but it didn't help me out (probably because i have more libraries and the order of them should be different)

What are your suggestions on what should i try?

P.s. modules that im using are:

```
opencv_imgcodecs
opencv_imgproc
opencv_highgui
opencv_video
opencv_videoio
opencv_tracking
opencv_core
opencv_optflow
```